# Problem with background in table when emulating Iphone Max Pro 12

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to emulate my app in different Iphone models but I'm also having the same mistake when I use a Max Pro 12. Anytime I use a tableViewContoller it seems not to fill the background cells completely. Just check my pictures. In the rest of models, including Max Pro 11 it's working ok. I don`t have any constraints because the I can't add them when I use tableViewController. Any suggestion?

Here you have my code.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
class MenuCustomCellController: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imEvento: UIImageView!  
    @IBOutlet weak var txtNombreEvento: UILabel!   
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFechaEvento: UILabel!   
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEstadoEvento: UILabel!
}
class MenuInicialTableController: UITableViewController {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var celdaUsuarios: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var celdaEventos: UITableViewCell! 
    @IBOutlet weak var celdaBuscarEventos: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var celdaGraficos: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var celdaCerrar: UITableViewCell!   
    @IBOutlet weak var celdaAyuda: UITableViewCell!
    
   
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MenuInicialTableController.tapFunction))
                celdaCerrar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                celdaCerrar.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        let background = UIView()
        tableView.backgroundView = background
        tableView.backgroundView?.aplicarFondoDegradado()
        tableView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        tableView.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.white.cgColor
        tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        celdaUsuarios.layer.borderWidth = 1
        celdaUsuarios.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.white.cgColor
        celdaUsuarios.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        celdaUsuarios.contentView.aplicarFondoMenuUsuarios()
        celdaEventos.layer.borderWidth = 1
        celdaEventos.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.white.cgColor
        celdaEventos.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        celdaEventos.contentView.aplicarFondoMenuEventos()
        celdaGraficos.layer.borderWidth = 1
        celdaGraficos.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.white.cgColor
        celdaGraficos.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        celdaGraficos.contentView.aplicarFondoMenuEventos()
        celdaCerrar.layer.borderWidth = 1
        celdaCerrar.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.white.cgColor
        celdaCerrar.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        celdaCerrar.contentView.aplicarFondoMenuUsuarios()
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "MENÚ PRINCIPAL"
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
        
    }

  
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    //Dos filas por sección
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    @objc
     func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
         exit(0)
     }
}
```

And here you have how I apply gradients:

```
func aplicarFondoMenuUsuarios() {
        let colorInicio =  UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorFin = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 190/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        if let gradientLayer = layer.sublayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer {
                gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio,colorFin]
        }
        else{
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio, colorFin]
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.50)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.50, y: 1.00)
            gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
            self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
            
        }

func aplicarFondoMenuEventos() {
        let colorInicio =  UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorFin = UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 0/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        if let gradientLayer = layer.sublayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer {
                gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio,colorFin]
        }
        else{
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.colors = [colorInicio, colorFin]
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.50)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.50, y: 1.00)
            gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
            self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `viewWillAppear` for layout-code. And not for TapGestures either. Move the three first lines (tap-related) into `viewDidLoad`, and put the rest into `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){}`.

There are a lot of other stuff you *should* do as well, like subclassing the cells and have them perform their gradients at the time of their own layout, and you should also remove `let background = UIView()` and instead just say `tableView.backgroundView = UIView()` in viewDidLoad (not in willAppear and not in viewDidLayoutSubviews).

Comment: Thanks for the help...all your changes applyed and everything works. I'll remeber it for the future. I have just a few weeks of experience with swift so I really aprreciate any help :)